# Seaborn.PointPlot Error Bars Not Displaying

Tags: python, seaborn

I am attempting to use Seaborn.pointplot to graphically plot points, as well as, display the relative variable relationship between each point via error bars. However, the errors bars are not displaying and I am instead only provided with the "point". Here is my code:

```
ax = sns.pointplot(x="Rank", y="Yld_Vol_Dr", data=df)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit - thanks for those answered - the issue was indeed the df I was inputting. I removed a dissolve step I was taking to provide the error data necessary for the point plot error bars.

Comment: where is the error data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errorbars are the confidence interval estimate, in order to get an error you have to have several examples for the given value of `Rank` to calculate the standard deviation.